# How to get privateKey as a org.springframework.core.io.Resource

Tags: spring-integration

I am using spring integration to connect to SFTP Server using a private key.
The private key is coming into the application as a external string.  How to use the key in the below code:

```
 <bean id="test"
        class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
        <property name="host" value="${host}" />
        <property name="privateKey" value="" />
        <property name="port" value="${port}" />
        <property name="user" value="${username}" />
        <property name="allowUnknownKeys" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that your key is encoded like some string, then you need to consider to wrap it into the `ByteArrayResource`.

Let's assume that you have it as a property in some file and you use a properties placeholder:

```
<bean id="test"
    class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="${host}" />
    <property name="privateKey">
        <bean class="org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource">
              <constructor-arg value="#{'${my.sftp.private.key}'.bytes}"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="port" value="${port}" />
    <property name="user" value="${username}" />
    <property name="allowUnknownKeys" value="true" />
</bean>
```